# How to split angular code in two script file for single page application

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page application where i want to split my code in two separate js files, like this -
    Script1.js -

```
 var app = angular.module("AngularJs", ["ui.router"])
                     .config(function ($stateProvider) {
                         $stateProvider
                           .state("home", {
                              url:"/home",
                               templateUrl: "Template/Home.html",
                               controller: "homeController",
                               controllerAs: "homectrl"
                           })
                        .state("courses", {
                            url: "/courses",
                            templateUrl: "Template/Courses.html",
                            controller: "coursesController",
                            controllerAs: "Coursectrl"
                        })                       
                                .state("newregistration", {
                                    //  url: "/students",
                                   templateUrl: "Template/NewRegistration.html",
                                    controller: "newregistration",
                                    controllerAs: "newregistrationctrl"
                                })                      
                     })
```

i have defined controller for all the state

```
    .controller("homeController", function () {
         this.message = "Home Page";
     })
            .controller("coursesController", function () {
                this.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
                this.message = "Courses Page";
            })

Now problem is that i want to define other controller on other script file - 
Script2.js -    
.controller("newregistration", function () {
    this.meassage = "New Employee Registration sfdsf";
})
```

how to separate the code into two different js files.

Answer (score 1):

Example of separation

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module("AngularJs", ["ui.router"])
```

**Config.js**

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
                         $stateProvider
                           .state("home", {
                              url:"/home",
                               templateUrl: "Template/Home.html",
                               controller: "homeController",
                               controllerAs: "homectrl"
                           })
                        .state("courses", {
                            url: "/courses",
                            templateUrl: "Template/Courses.html",
                            controller: "coursesController",
                            controllerAs: "Coursectrl"
                        })                       
                                .state("newregistration", {
                                    //  url: "/students",
                                   templateUrl: "Template/NewRegistration.html",
                                    controller: "newregistration",
                                    controllerAs: "newregistrationctrl"
                                })                      
                     })
```

**Controllers.js**

```
app.controller("homeController", function () {
         this.message = "Home Page";
     })
app.controller("coursesController", function () {
                this.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
                this.message = "Courses Page";
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Define an app**
 app.js
 var app = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

**Put your controllers in separate files like this**

**HomeCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('demoApp').controller("homeController", function () {
 this.message = "Home Page";
});
```

**CoursesCtrl.js**

```
 angular.module('demoApp').controller("coursesController", function () {
      this.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
      this.message = "Courses Page";
 });
```

**RegistrationCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('demoApp').controller("newregistration", function () {
     this.meassage = "New Employee Registration sfdsf";
});
```

Your HTML would then include the app and use the controllers

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="HomeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="CoursesCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="RegistrationCtrl.js"></script>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
<div ng-controller='HomeCtrl'>
  This will access home controller
</div>
<div ng-controller='CoursesCtrl'>
  This will access courses controller
</div>
<div ng-controller='RegistrationCtrl'>
  This will access registration controller
</div>
</body>
```